# Getting HTTP 404.15 Error - Not Found ...because the query string is too long

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, saml, http-get

I'm fetching the information from the server. The get method is being used in the SAML Response I'm receiving from the server, which is producing an error:

The query string is too long, resulting in HTTP Error 404.15, not found.

I have attempted to obtain a SAML response from the IDP (identity provider) that performs the authentication and directs me to the page upon successful authentication. What I am receiving is a SAML response of the Get method type, which produces the HTTP Error 404.15 not found message due to the length of the query string.

I want to know whether there is a secure way for me to go around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The IdP should send the SAML response in an HTTP Post. The SAML specification doesn't support sending the SAML response as a query string parameter for the very reason you're seeing.

Comment: Hi ComponentSpace, 
Thanks for the sharing, Is there any other way? 
else I have to start working on the SAML response in HTTP post binding, Also help from members is appreciated

Comment: The "Conformance Requirements for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0" specification states that SAML responses may be sent using either the HTTP-Post or HTTP-Artifact binding. HTTP-Post is the most common and simpler of the two bindings.

Comment: Hi, I tried building the post binding to receive the saml response, to avoid the HTTP 404.15 error, but in this I am not able to do the authentication, means on home page when I click the login button I am redirected to the IDP for authentication then after authentication I am redirected to my homepage. But now after building the Post binding after clicking the saml2 button I am directly redirected to my Homepage no authentication nothing.
Any help in this is appreciated.